# Wavelength in Multiple Lossy Layers

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations, wavelength

I would like to derive an equation for the wavelength of a plane electromagnetic wave (normal incidence) in each layer of a multilayered lossy medium, as shown below.

[image]

Which equations are required for this?

I have found some equations which may be applicable, but I think that they are an over-simplification. One approach derives an average velocity by averaging the complex permittivity across all layers, i.e.

$$\epsilon_{avg} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} r_i \epsilon_i $$ where $$r_i = \frac{d_i}{d_{total}} $$

The average phase velocity is then:
$$ v_{avg} = Re(\frac{c}{\sqrt{\epsilon_{avg}}}) $$

and so

$$ \lambda = v_{avg}/f $$

i.e. this calculates a constant wavelength $ \lambda $ by averaging all lossy layers.

Is this valid, or is there a better way to express the wavelength in each layer

Comment: Welcome PikaPika, can you share what you tried so far? Otherwise this may be closed as homework-like, see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on how to ask an on topic question

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer-matrix_method_(optics)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I have used the Transfer Matrix Method to model the E-field and H-field distribution inside these layers, but I don't understand how this method can be used to express the wavelength in each layer. Could you explain this please?